# Data Change on CURL Respond PHP

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Just one question. I got an cURL based code, and it send a request to the serwer, then if the respond is 'valid' it's making a sql query, but if the respond is 'busy' I need to change the proxy which the script is using.

I'm making it this way:

```
$proxys = file('http_proxy.txt');
...then...
for($n = 0, $count = count($proxys); $n <= $count; $n++) {
...and to change the proxy I used something like this:
$proxy = $proxys[$n + 1];
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Regards.

Comment: Since you are already looping them with a `for`, the `$proxy = $proxys[$n + 1];` should be redundant - you should write it so that you would just [`continue;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) instead...

Answer (score 1):

For starters, `file('http_proxy.txt');` will retain the newlines in your file, so use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to omit this. Then, you could use `break;` to stop the loop after succesfully using CURL on a proxy:

```
$proxys = file('http_proxy.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($proxys as $proxy)
{
    $response = sendRequestTo($proxy);
    if($response == 'valid')
    {
        performQuery($proxy);
        break;
    }
}
```